# SystemTap on Android

Tags: android, linux, systemtap

when I executed the command ' staprun ' on the android , I met following problem  :

```
# /data/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/staprun /data/local/msyscall_all.ko
  /data/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/staprun: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
#
```

the module msyscall_all.ko is cross-compiled with the kernel that my android run on.

firstly, I am sure that msyscall_all.ko is exactlly right , because I use command ' insomd ' and ' lsmod ' to ensure it is right .I did it as following :

```
# lsmod
 omaplfb 8986 0 - Live 0xbf032000
 pvrsrvkm 137346 29 omaplfb, Live 0xbf000000
# insmod /data/local/msyscall_all.ko
# lsmod
  msyscall_all 1121778 0 - Live 0xbf037000
  omaplfb 8986 0 - Live 0xbf032000
  pvrsrvkm 137346 29 omaplfb, Live 0xbf000000
#
```

secondly, I followed the instruction in :http://omappedia.org/wiki/Systemtap#Systemtap_1.0_code_update_for_OMAP_ARM_platforms

And my systemtap-1.0-omap was cross-compiled successfully!! Howerver, after I used 'adb push' to pushed the systemtap-1.0-omap to my android device and ran it ,I got the error below :

**/data/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/staprun: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected**

when the 'staprun' was ran on the ubuntu ,it gave me advice how run ' staprun ' , and when it was run on the android device ,it went wrong :

```
# /data/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/staprun
  /data/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/staprun: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
# exit
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd systemtap-1.0-omap/bin/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin$ ./staprun 
ERROR: Need a module name or path to load.

./staprun [-v]  [-c cmd ] [-x pid] [-u user] [-A|-L|-d]
  [-b bufsize] [-o FILE [-D] [-S size[,N]]] MODULE [module-options]
  -v              Increase verbosity.
  -c cmd          Command 'cmd' will be run and staprun will
                  exit when it does.  The '_stp_target' variable
                  will contain the pid for the command.
  -x pid          Sets the '_stp_target' variable to pid.
  -o FILE         Send output to FILE. This supports strftime(3)
                  formats for FILE.
  -b buffer size  The systemtap module specifies a buffer size.
                  Setting one here will override that value.  The
                  value should be an integer between 1 and 4095 
                  which be assumed to be the buffer size in MB.
                  That value will be per-cpu in bulk mode.
  -L              Load module and start probes, then detach.
  -A              Attach to loaded systemtap module.
  -d              Delete a module.  Only detached or unused modules
                  the user has permission to access will be deleted. Use "*"
                  (quoted) to delete all unused modules.
  -D              Run in background. This requires '-o' option.
  -S size[,N]     Switches output file to next file when the size
                  of file reaches the specified size. The value
                  should be an integer greater than 1 which is
                  assumed to be the maximum file size in MB.
                  When the number of output files reaches N, it
                  switches to the first output file. You can omit
                  the second argument.
  MODULE can be either a module name or a module path.  If a
  module name is used, it is looked for in the following
  directory: /lib/modules/`uname -r`/systemtap
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/systemtap-1.0-omap/bin$
```

I have tried my best , but I can not solve it !!

Comment: Please share how you solved it.

Comment: In fact , it is very easy to solve the problem . I have beening thinking I used a wrong toolchain , so I downloaded another one from the web and replaced the older one . And It exactlly did work !